# Would this be a correct tag in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I am a newbie to grails.

Would this be a correct syntax for the  tag?

```
<g:each in="${empactUser.getAuthorities()}">
    <g:if test="it.getAuthority().startsWith("ROLE_PROJECTID")">
    <g:link action="edit" params="[id: it.getAuthority(13).]"> Project </g:link>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this...

```
<g:each in="${empactUser.getAuthorities()}">
    <g:if test="${it.getAuthority().startsWith("ROLE_PROJECTID")}">
        <g:link action="edit" params="[id: it.getAuthority(13).id]">Project</g:link>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running this myself it does appear you are missing your gstring syntax on the if tag

```
<g:if test="${it.getAuthority().startsWith("ROLE_PROJECTID")}">
```